# UIImageView animating pictures

Tags: xcode, animation, uiimageview

How do I cycle the images in an UIImageView?

Say I have three images, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg. How do I get the pictures to change ad infinitum until the user presses something...

Answer (score 1):

This describes it pretty well: [[Link]](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html)

```
// create the view that will execute our animation
 UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

 // load all the frames of our animation
 campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.gif"], nil];

 // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
 campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
 // repeat the annimation forever
 campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
 // start animating
 [campFireView startAnimating];
 // add the animation view to the main window 
 [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for and SO fast. Had to wait a few minutes before Stack would let me accept this as the answer :-)